# Display JSON data objects in React Native App

Tags: json, typescript, react-native

I have a JSON file like the one below, and I am trying to use this data in a React native application.

```json
[
  {
    "001": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "fare": 0,
        "city": "Colombo"
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "fare": 30,
        "city": "Maligawaththa"
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "fare": 38,
        "city": "Kelanithissa"
      },
      {
        "index": 3,
        "fare": 50,
        "city": "4 Kanuwa / Biyagama road"
      },
      {
        "index": 4,
        "fare": 61,
        "city": "Thorana Junction"
      },
      {
        "index": 5,
        "fare": 73,
        "city": "Kelaniya University"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "100": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "fare": "446.00",
        "city": "Mulgampola"
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "fare": "452.00",
        "city": "Kandy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "101": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "fare": "446.00",
        "city": "Mulgampola"
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "fare": "452.00",
        "city": "Kandy"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I need to display the keys of the each objects (001, 100, 101..) in a `Picker` element and after user selects one of the options, I need to display the cities in a separate `DropDown` element.

```ts
const keys = data.map((item) => Object.keys(item)[0]);

const cities = data.flatMap((item: any) => {
  const routeNumber = Object.keys(item)[0];
  return item[routeNumber].map((subItem: any) => ({
    label: subItem.city,
    value: subItem.index,
  }));
});
```

I tried to access each object like above, and it does not work. Appreciate it if you could help me to correct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the source structure to something usable. For example

```js
const data = [{"001":[{"index":0,"fare":0,"city":"Colombo"},{"index":1,"fare":30,"city":"Maligawaththa"},{"index":2,"fare":38,"city":"Kelanithissa"},{"index":3,"fare":50,"city":"4 Kanuwa / Biyagama road"},{"index":4,"fare":61,"city":"Thorana Junction"},{"index":5,"fare":73,"city":"Kelaniya University"}]},{"100":[{"index":0,"fare":"446.00","city":"Mulgampola"},{"index":1,"fare":"452.00","city":"Kandy"}]},{"101":[{"index":0,"fare":"446.00","city":"Mulgampola"},{"index":1,"fare":"452.00","city":"Kandy"}]}];

const keys = data.flatMap(Object.keys);
const keyCityMap = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map((obj) =>
    Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, arr]) => [
      key,
      arr.map(({ city }) => city),
    ]),
  ),
);

console.log('keys:', keys);
console.log('keyCityMap:', keyCityMap);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Then you can use `keys` to drive your *picker* options and lookup the array of cities using `keyCityMap[pickerSelection]`.

This assumes that each *key* only ever appears once in the `data` array. It's not really clear why `data` is an array at all though.

---

If you need more than just the city name, use this instead to map the entire object

```js
const keyCityMap = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map((obj) => Object.entries(obj).flat()),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Filter of Array

```js
data = [{
    '001': [{
        index: 0,
        fare: 0.0,
        city: 'Colombo',
      },
      {
        index: 1,
        fare: 30.0,
        city: 'Maligawaththa',
      },
      {
        index: 2,
        fare: 38.0,
        city: 'Kelanithissa',
      },
      {
        index: 3,
        fare: 50.0,
        city: '4 Kanuwa / Biyagama road',
      },
      {
        index: 4,
        fare: 61.0,
        city: 'Thorana Junction',
      },
      {
        index: 5,
        fare: 73.0,
        city: 'Kelaniya University',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    100: [{
        index: 0,
        fare: '446.00',
        city: 'Mulgampola',
      },
      {
        index: 1,
        fare: '452.00',
        city: 'Kandy',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    101: [{
        index: 0,
        fare: '446.00',
        city: 'Mulgampola',
      },
      {
        index: 1,
        fare: '452.00',
        city: 'Kandy',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const keys = data.map((item) => Object.keys(item)[0]);
console.log("keys : ", keys);

const selectedKey = keys[0];

const cities = data.filter((item) => item[selectedKey])[0][selectedKey];
console.log("cities : ", cities);
```